# Why is the column value not persisting after Postgres function triggers after update?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, postgresql-triggers

I have a table called `Projects` where I need to set a certain column value after an update is executed and the record matches certain conditions. The function triggers correctly and there are no errors but the updated column value does not persist.

Here's my SQL:

```
create table projects (
  id int not null primary key,
  status varchar,
  number varchar
);

CREATE FUNCTION update_number() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
declare
    status_code  varchar;
begin
    SELECT project_codes.code INTO status_code FROM project_codes WHERE project_codes.status = NEW.status;
    NEW.number := CONCAT('CA-', status_code, '-', nextval('project_sequence'));
    RAISE INFO 'Project: %', NEW;
    RETURN NEW;
end
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_number_trig
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON projects
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.status = 'CAPITAL')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_number();
```

I'm running the following command to test this:

`UPDATE projects SET status = 'CAPITAL' WHERE id = '123456';`

The function executes after the update operation, I see in the console that the `RAISE` prints:

> Project: (123456, CAPITAL, CA-2DC-1)

But when I do a `SELECT` on the projects table, the number column is blank.

Why is setting the column value not persisting?

Comment: You can only change values I. A before update trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying `NEW` only has an effect in `BEFORE` triggers. In an `AFTER` trigger, the row has already been written, and the modified `NEW` you return will at most affect other `AFTER` triggers that come after you.

You need to use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: Is it also fine to keep it as an `AFTER UPATE` trigger but change the function to do `UPDATE projects SET number=CONCAT('CA-', status_code, '-', nextval('project_sequence')) WHERE projects.id = NEW.id`

Comment: No, that  is not fine at all, but leads to an infinite loop.